# What does it mean to build a project?

Tags: build, project, terminology

When it comes to programming what does it really mean to build a project?

From my experience it usually means to compile a program. But what if it is a project that doesn't need compilation like a Python program or Django web application?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is NOT about programming as defined in the FAQ, it may belong on Programmers . . .

Comment: @BinaryWorrier In my mind, its one of those items that probably the FAQ should allow, but to describe it properly in the FAQ would open the door for too many "should not be allowed" items.  Certainly some "can you define a phrase" questions don't merit an answer on StackOverflow, but this particular phrase is so central to development it might merit an exception.

Comment: A good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622520/8315879)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, building a project is not really about "building a project" at all.  It is about "building items" that are considered to be the deliverables of the project.

In some circles the deliverables are also named "artifacts" or "build artifacts"; however, "to build a project" is really abbreviated speech for "to build the deliverables of a project from the sources".

Answer (score 0):

Not having python or django in mind - because I am not familiar with them; however, thinking back to visual basic, which never used to be compiled, a person would build a p-code file that contained their program and a runtime library would interpret it.  It wasn't compiled, but it could run as though it had been.  I imagine that building a python program would be to create a file which could be interpreted by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Since there hasn't been any sufficient answer in the last years I'll take the leap.

Building the project means to create the **deliverable item that can be used in the target environment**.

Examples

- A Python library can be built into a wheel so it can be used from another program.
- A C program compiles into an executable binary that can be run by the user on the OS.
- A Django application can be built into a docker image so it's directly deployable on the cloud.